# Storing last user activity with Ajax and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have an *Ajax* which sends *username/id* to PHP every second in order to know which user is currently online.
PHP then  takes the *user id* and updates it's field in an `activity` table with the current time for the given user.

Is this approach correct, because it uses a lot of CPU from my current hosting plan (and that's just for one session)?

Comment: do you need to do it each second? sessions use at least2 min, sometimes 5min or evn 10min.

Comment: I need more accurate last activity. I will use it for chat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of continuously sending data to the server, update the activity for a given user upon navigation. This approach comes with advantages.

- It will be gentle on system resources
- It will be easy for you to track whether a user is active or not